# Spring Application throwing error and WAR not building

Tags: java, spring-boot

I would like to deploy the package onto `tomcat` so tried extending it with `SpringBootServletInitializer` and the following error occurred but on normal deploy without any `SpringBootServletInitializer` there seems to be no error.

What am i doing wrong?

My `build.gradle` file looks like this

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
}

group 'com.nithin.ms'
version '0.5.0'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.4'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.8'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.0.4.RELEASE'
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:2.0.4.RELEASE'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

The error is

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [in.nithin.Application]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:184) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:316) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:233) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:271) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:91) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1258) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at in.nithin.Application.main(Application.java:28) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:169) ~[spring-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.retrieveBeanMethodMetadata(ConfigurationClassParser.java:393) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:318) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:202) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:170) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContext
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:158) ~[spring-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    ... 21 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

My `Application.java` file looks like this

```
package in.nithin;

// Our packages
import in.nithin.property.FileStorageProperties;

// Required packages
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

// Application starts here
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
@EnableConfigurationProperties({
        FileStorageProperties.class
})
public class Application  extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

EDIT-1

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.4.RELEASE)

2018-09-07 12:03:18.285  INFO 10917 --- [           main] in.nithin.Application                  : Starting Application on XPS-L401X with PID 10917 (/home/signzy/code/java/main/fileupload/out/production/classes started by signzy in /home/signzy/code/java/main/fileupload)
2018-09-07 12:03:18.324  INFO 10917 --- [           main] in.nithin.Application                  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-09-07 12:03:18.639  INFO 10917 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@2145433b: startup date [Fri Sep 07 12:03:18 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-09-07 12:03:21.313  WARN 10917 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
2018-09-07 12:03:21.350  INFO 10917 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-09-07 12:03:21.370 ERROR 10917 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:155) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1258) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at in.nithin.Application.main(Application.java:28) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getWebServerFactory(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:204) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:178) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 8 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContext` means that the jar `javax.servlet.jar is missing in your classpath

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api
compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.1.0'
```

Comment: You shouldn't need this, since `spring-boot-starter-web` depends on `spring-web`,  which in turn already depends on `javax.servlet-api`, so basically it should be on the classpath already.

Comment: @g00glen00b But the exception say the opposide

Comment: @Jens That means there is a different issue, either he is running the application without running it on Tomcat itself, or his Maven repo is corrupt.

Comment: @Nithin same exception?

Comment: No different exception 

`org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.`

Comment: @Nithin without the whole stacktrace it is hard to say

Comment: Added the console output at **EDIT-1**

Comment: Using `IntelliJ`

Hitting run `Application.main()` on local

`gradle war` for building `war`

Comment: @Nithin and than you put the war into a tomcat right?

Comment: Yep, Plan to deploy it onto tomcat.

The error on tomcat is

FAIL - Application at context path [/fileupload-0.5.0] could not be started
FAIL - Encountered exception [org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/fileupload-0.5.0]]]

Comment: @Nithin *plan*  means actually you don't do it? This part of the logfile doesn't help

Comment: I do deploy it on tomcat itself, but it's throwing error on local as well a on tomcat server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179615/discussion-between-jens-and-nithin).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on spring-boot web app deployment with Tomcat. I resolved the issue by adding servlet-api dependency with Provided scope.

@Grab(group='javax.servlet', module='javax.servlet-api', version='3.1.0', scope='provided')

after deployment of your app. In WEB-INF you will find folder called lib-provided which 
 consists other jars along with the servlet-api one.

Suggestions : Provided scope helps you to retain your deployment capability for embedded tomcat.